# how to subtract a sting in perl which contain hexadecimal number

Tags: string, perl

```
my $first = sprintf("%x",3730);
my $second = sprintf("%x",3700);
my $err = sprintf("%x",20);

if (($first - $second) > $err) {
    print "err";
}
else{
    print "done";
}
```

I want to print 'err' here but it is printing 'done'.

How can I do the subtraction in perl when both string contain hexadecimal number.

Comment: Why not carry out the comparison before converting to string? Use the 'hex' function.

Comment: @Foxish perhaps it's just a minimal example and there is a lot of stuff happening in between, or OP has no direct control on input, or ...

Comment: @Christoph Perhaps... :D

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` will give you `Argument "e74" isn't numeric in subtraction (-)` etc. Which should explain things. Strings that do not start with numbers are converted to zero `0`. (And of course, perl has no way to know that `14` is really `0x14`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( hex($first) - hex($second) > hex($err) ) {
```